# AWS RDS Postgres random reads incredibly slow

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We are running a

```
r5.4xlarge RDS PG 10.5 instance with 10.000 provisioned IOPS.
```

When runing a query like

```
select count(f3) from table 
where f1 = 'x' and f2 between x and y;
```

it will take >15 seconds to return for ~20k values.
There is and index covering (f1,f2). F3 is not on the index. Explain analyse shows that the time is spent on an INDEX SCAN.

It seems that whenever the required data is not in cache and has to be read from disk we get those slow response times.

We achieve the same results with both, the default parameter groups and changing some values as proposed here https://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/#/

Are we having fundamentally wrong expectations towards RDS here, or are we missing some essential detail in the configuration?

Comment: How many rows do you have? The index scan makes sense as you're doing a range operation.  And when is the last time you reindexed?